# Trying to Commit with vim. <esc> :wq not working?

Tags: git, vim

I am trying to commit with vim. I am seeing everywhere that you save the commit by doing `<esc> :wq`. But I do `esc`, and once I hit `:` it seems to go back to edit mode and writes the wq in my commit message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your .vimrc file along with this question. You might have more success posting this on the Vi Stack Exchange site http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mat correct! I am hitting the esc key

Comment: You should probably use another, simpler, editor: `$ git config --global core.editor "nano"`.

Comment: @romainl Thanks! If I can use a different editor that's preferred.

Comment: Can you try the suggestion of Ingo Karkat and post the results? I'm interested. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

> But I do esc, and once I hit : it seems to go back to edit mode

It looks like your Vim is in *easy mode*, emulating other modeless editors. See `:help easy`.

To quit in this mode, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> followed by `:wq` <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You could also turn off easy mode via `:set noinsertmode`, and (if you haven't yet given up on Vim) fix the invocation, probably in your Git config (i.e. remove the `-y` argument from the `vim` call).

Comment: Very interesting, however the author describes only `wq` not `:wq` inserted, and even going 'back' to edit mode. That doesn't aligns very well with easy mode, which will not leave insert mode on `ESC` and will also inserts the `:`

Comment: @mxlian: Right, it's just a guess based on the little (and possibly imprecise) information that's in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem: make sure your keyboard configuration didn't change language.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix, try another alternative that doesn't use the `:`

```
<Esc>ZZ
```

You may have a problem in your mappings, but you will have to post your .vimrc for some one to help you

Answer (score 1):

you are suppose to use sudo as its not allowing you to edit file
steps

1. `sudo vi filepath # for ex /etc/paths`
2. press <kbd>i</kbd>
3. write in file
4. press <kbd>esc</kbd> and type `:wq` followed by <kbd>enter</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
<esc>:qa!
```

to exit vim and unsave all changes, hope it helps:)

Comment: OP wants to save changes, so telling them how not to save them is not really helpful.